# C# / jQuery using ajax, not using the encosia example

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I am playing with C# and jQuery (Ajax). In a effort to keep the C# code as short and clean as possible when creating a Ajax request, without using the Encosia example (in short without ASP.NET for the Ajax calls). The response can be XML, JSON or plain (parts) HTML.

I got a working version, but is this preferable to do? Or should I consider a other method?

I do get 1 warning (for the ajax.aspx page) in VS2010 express (a search of this error doens't gives me a [satisfied answer](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/264711/validation-the-element-html-occurs-too-few-times))

**Warning**
    Validation (): Element 'html' occurs too few times.

**default.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

   <div id="Result"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(function () {
         $.ajax({
            url: "AJAX.aspx",
            success: function (data) { $("#Result").html(data); }
         });
      });
   </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**ajax.aspx (there is only this line on this page)**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
                       CodeFile="AJAX.aspx.cs" Inherits="AJAX" %>
```

**ajax.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

public partial class AJAX : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write("Hello world");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well it's like the error says: you have to have `<html>` tags to have a valid html document. Since your page doesn't seem to use a master page, there's probably no html tags being rendered. There's short and concise and then there's too short.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I think you should add to your code is in relation to the jQuery ajax call.
You have not explicitly specified all of the settings. I use the following to set up my default values for all of my ajax calls, which can be overridden at any stage by an individual ajax call:

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            utilities.ajaxErrorAlert(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```